# wpf using a windows form

Tags: wpf, image

I have a windows form that handles drag and drop of images just fine.Because I cannot find a way to do this in WPF can I add the form to a page and will the drag and drop still work? The images being dragged are from outside of app. 
                                                      Thanks,   Betsy

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) in WPF to host Windows Forms controls. This will meet your requirements. Otherwise, take a look at [Drag & Drop in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx). This is fairly easy to implement.

Comment: +1 I've used WindowsFormHost in many situations successfully. Learn how to do things in WPF it's important, but time matters too.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the reply. I am learning WPF and I enjoy it much more than WindowsForms!!! The problem in WPF with the drag and drop images seems to be much more complicated than WindowsForm. I am creating a new version of my program thats why I thought maybe I could add the form to a page and still have d&d of images but there is something concerning airspace when dragging over elements in Wpf.